# SOLR matching phrases (SHINGLE FILTER)

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Im building an app using SOLR 5.2 and I need this type of match:

if i have stored fields  name:"**bla1 bla2**" and name:"**bla2 something bla3**"
when i query something like name:"something **bla1 bla2 something bla3** bla4"
i need it to match **both terms**.

So what i ended up doing is defining this type of field:

I use Keyword Tokenizer for **indexing**.

I use Whitespace Tokenizer and Shingle filter for **query** so i get something like this "bla tra kla zla cla" outputs "bla tra", "bla tra kla", "bla tra kla zla" .......

I have tried in analysis and shingling works fine but the problem is when i execute my query with real data it just doesnt seem to find a match.

```
 <fieldType name="shingleparse" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>      
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"/>
  </analyzer>   
</fieldType>

<field name="name" type="shingleparse" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Comment: [Keyword Tokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer) treats the entire text field as a single token. So when you are indexing your data, this can be see like a single token `bla2 something bla3`.

Comment: that is exactly how it is supposed to be treated because for instance if i query smth like  "**bla2 something bla3 bla4 bla5**" i will get shingles "**bla2 something**" , "**bla2 something bla3**", ... and it should match but for some reason it doesnt

Comment: So in your example, the **first one** (`bla1 bla2`) is matching and not the **second one** (`bla2 something bla3`)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/j79TQ here is the picture of what i want...  both of these queries should match

Comment: Use the "Analysis" page under the web interface to see why the shingle isn't generating the match you think it should..

Comment: Problem is it is generating exactly the shingles i want but it just doesnt match them thats the problem

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using an **AND** query, so this will search for every shingles : a query like `bla2 something bla3` will search `bla2 AND bla2 something AND bla2 something bla3`.

Comment: i've tried adding the OR query by adding dismax and mm=2 but problem is in parsed query it just doesnt seem to work how can i change it is there other way perhaps in scheme

Comment: Add a screenshot that shows the analysis for both the indexed and the queried values.

Comment: @BrainOverflow did you end up solving this problem? I'm facing the exact same one and I would love to know if it's possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works for your requirement.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
         <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem cause if i for instance query exact word "**bla1 bla2**" it matches but if i query name:"**bla1 bla2 ttttttt**" this doesnt match and i want it to match

Comment: it will match...check these at the analysis page http://localhost/solr/admin/analysis.jsp

Comment: I tried the second one as well, it matches for the above fieldType

Comment: for me it doesnt i will post pictures in post

Comment: did you changes the fieldType and reindexed it..? It would be good if you analyse it in  localhost/solr/testCore/admin/analysis.jsp check here ...http://imgur.com/rgnIA9K

Comment: Bear in mind that this will match the opposite direction as well, and queries where the terms aren't close either. The shingle approach will only match tokens following each other in the same order.

Comment: @MatsLindh : agree with you...is there really a need of shingle approach is the question...if the search is to be in phrases...then yes go for the ShingleFilterFactory

Comment: yes i did reindex but this doesnt help + my analysis tool isnt the same as yours which version of solr are u using?